# Remapping keys system wide in linux, not just in X

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to do the typical remapping of capslock to control, but I also want to remap left control to be a second super key.  I can do this fine with xmodmap, but as soon as I switch to a virtual terminal (ie what comes up when you hit ctrl-alt-f1), I'm back to being stuck with default key mappings.  So what I'm mainly looking for is a way to remap the keys in the virtual terminals as well.

I'm ok with having to use xmodmap for stuff in X, and a separate method for virtual terminals, but I'd prefer to do something that handles both situations if possible.

Comment: Similar question, more answers.  http://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177024/remap-keyboard-on-the-linux-console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use [`loadkeys`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/loadkeys) for your console. See also [keymaps](http://linux.die.net/man/5/keymaps) and [`dumpkeys`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dumpkeys).

Comment: Cool.  Do you know if this specific to the console or will the changes made with loadkeys persist in X as well?

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html looks like I need xmodmap and loadkeys

Answer (score 11):

From [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/223674/177864)

As far as your <kbd>caps</kbd>-><kbd>ctrl</kbd> goes, this works. You might be able to use this same method to remap your super key as well.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/keyboard
```

Now find the line that starts with `XKBOPTIONS`, and add `ctrl:nocaps` to
make <kbd>caps</kbd> an additional <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or `ctrl:swapcaps` to swap them.

For example, mine looks like

```
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_alt,compose:menu,ctrl:nocaps"
```

then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

The reason this way is better is that it will take effect on the virtual consoles (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) as well as in the graphical desktop.