# How to change console keymap in Linux?

Tags: linux, console, keymap

I'd like to exchange <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> in console (not in X, and use `xev`), how can I do it?

My OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The tools to manipulate the keyboard layout on the [virtual consoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) are `loadkeys`, `dumpkeys` and `showkey`. Read their manpages and inform yourself about their intricacies.

Note that these tools only work in a virtual console, not in a terminal emulator in a graphical environment like gnome. The learn about the difference read [this question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal).

Here is a short guide to do what you want:

1. Save your current keyboard layout:

   ```
    $ dumpkeys > backup.kmap
   ```

   In case something goes wrong you might be able restore your keymap using the command:

   ```
    $ sudo loadkeys backup.kmap
   ```

   If the keyboard is so messed up that you can't even do this then your only option not involving ancient kernel magic is to reboot.
2. Check which keycodes are assigned to your keys:

   ```
    $ showkey
   ```

   Now press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key and the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> key. The keycodes should show up on the screen. Note the keycodes. On my system the <kbd>ESC</kbd> has the keycode 1 and <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> has the keycode 58. `showkey` will terminate after 10 seconds of inactivity (at least it does on my ubuntu 10.04).
3. Note the names of the <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> keys from dumpkeys:

   ```
    $ dumpkeys | grep 1
    ...
    keycode   1 = Escape
    ...
    $ dumpkeys | grep 58
    ...
    keycode  58 = CtrlL_Lock
    ...
   ```
4. Note the keymap line from dumpkeys:

   ```
    $ dumpkeys | head -1
    keymaps 0-127
   ```
5. Create a keymap file which switches <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd>:

   ```
    keymaps 0-127
    keycode   1 = CtrlL_Lock
    keycode  58 = Escape
   ```
6. Load the keymap:

   ```
    $ sudo loadkeys swap_esc_capslock.kmap
   ```
7. Test: Testing the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> key is obvious. Just press they <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> key and check whether other keys come out capitalized. To test the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>. It should print `^[`. CTRL+V makes the shell print the next key verbatim instead of interpreting it.

To have this modification load on every reboot, put the following line in your `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
/usr/bin/loadkeys /path/to/swap_esc_capslock.kmap
```

Information gathered from various pages, including, but not limited to:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-15.html
- http://www.mail-archive.com/puredyne@goto10.org/msg01407.html
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=4591324#post4591324

Comment: You can also use `sudo setupcon --save` to make changes permanent, rather than editing rc.local. That's essentially the same as `dumpkeys < /dev/tty1 | gzip > /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz`

Comment: It is safer to use `/usr/bin/loadkeys` in `/etc/rc.local`since the path environment variable is not guaranteed to be set at this stage. And `sudo` is not needed in `rc.local`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom The command in `rc.local` executes every time the system boots.  @bukzor's `sudo setupcon` is _not_ in `rc.local`, it's a one-time setup command, which replaces the system default keymap, without adding any runtime startup code.  Adding `loadkeys`  to `rc.local`, adds extra start up code and duplicates what was already done by the system default loadkeys.  The `rc.local` method could actually be less safe because it depends on a non-standard path to the keymap.

Comment: I cannot verify @bukzor's statement about `setupcon`.   It appears that August made the assumption that the `sudo setupcon --save` would go into `rc.local` which I don't think is true, but if it does, you don't need  `sudo` in `rc.local`.  I think we need more info before updating your answer.  The main question is "How to install the modified keymap so that it gets loaded automatically during the boot process?"  I really don't know which is a better way, `rc.local` or installing a keymap, or even if installing a keymap will work.  I have been researching this lately and I'll check back here.

Comment: the `showkey` command isn't working for me as described. when I run it, I get a warning: "[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]". It still gives me the prompt to "press any key" but no key codes show up, just the character itself (i.e. 'a' appears if I press the 'a' key, and nothing happens at all if I press "Caps Lock"). help!!

Comment: it is worth noting that such a personal keymap is useful also to redefine the behaviour of keys already treated by the default keymap: when loaded with loadkeys, the directives in the default keymap will be replaced when they conflict with the new directives and conserved otherwise. This way, only changes to the keymap must be specified in the personal keymap.

Comment: If you’re worried about having to reboot if you mess up your keyboard, note that you can also restore the keyboard over an SSH session: `sudo loadkeys --console=/dev/tty3 < …`

Answer (score 4):

Use `ctrl:nocaps` instead of `ctrl:swapcaps` if you just want to have two <kbd>capslocks</kbd> key (capslock by another name is still super useless).

X11: (see also: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`)

```
sudo vim /etc/default/keyboard
    XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"
udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
sudo restart lightdm
```

Text console: (stolen from setupcon)

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/default/console-setup 
. /etc/default/keyboard
ckbcomp $acm_option $rules_option -model "$XKBMODEL" \
            "$XKBLAYOUT" "$XKBVARIANT" "$XKBOPTIONS" \
            | gzip -9 2>/dev/null >/etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
loadkeys /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
```

Comment: `setupcon` is not known on my system, do you have any info about source?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (22.04) the console keys are managed by the systemd service `keyboard-setup` (runs early - before login).
It is defined in `/lib/systemd/system/keyboard-setup.service`
(package: console-setup-linux).

The service will run `/lib/console-setup/keyboard-setup.sh` which will generate a new keymap with `setupcon -k` (or use a cached version).

Now `setupcon` (package: console-setup) is found in both `/bin/setupcon` and `/usr/bin/setupcon`; these are the same (shell scripts), given /bin --> /usr/bin.

Without a cached kmap.gz file, `setupcon -k` generates a gzipped keymap file in `/etc/console-setup/`. With a name that looks like: `cached_.*.kmap.gz`. E.g. I have: `cached_UTF-8_del.kmap.gz`.
The generated keymap file is loaded with `loadkeys`.

Configuration for `setupcon` is sourced from (both):

- /etc/default/console_setup
- /etc/default/keyboard

For `setupcon -k`, the relevant variables that these configuration files (shell scripts) set, (values are for me):

- CHARMAP=UTF-8
- BACKSPACE=del
- XKBLAYOUT=us
- XKBMODEL=pc105
- XKBVARIANT=
- XKBOPTIONS=

(Note: `localectl set-x11-keymap ...` writes `/etc/default/keyboard`.
If needed, read `man localectl`, there are commands to get the possible values for the `XKB*` variables.)

The configuration values are passed to `/bin/ckbcomp`, which is a perl script parsing all kind of X-files to generate the keymap (on stdout).

The `ckbcomp` script allows for user additions. It will add the contents of `/etc/console-setup/remap.inc` at the end of the generated keymap.
(Note: when CHARMAP is not UTF-8, `compose.$CHARMAP.inc` also gets included before `remap.inc`).

The `remap.inc` file has examples and is what you should be using if you want to make the mapping permanent.

So the answer to OP's question would be:

```
    ## run as root on a console
    cd /etc/console-setup

    {
        echo 'keycode 1 = CtrlL_Lock'
        echo 'keycode 58 = Escape'
    } > remap.inc ## Keep the comments? Use '>> remap.inc'.

    ## Remove cached items, so setupcon -k generates a new keymap.
    rm -f cached_*kmap.gz cached_keyboard_setup.sh

    reboot
```

Debian also has the packages console-setup and console-setup-linux. So it probably works there too.
I have not personally checked this works on Debian.