# Where are the keymaps in Debian? (Using loadkeys to change keymap.)

Tags: keyboard, debian, console, dvorak

From the actual console (e.g. `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`F3`), I'd like to use `sudo loadkeys dvorak` [as in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179855/how-do-i-temporarily-change-the-console-keymap-to-dvorak/).  While that automagically works in Ubuntu, Debian wants me to locate a keymap file.  I don't have the `/usr/share/keymaps` that is sometimes given as an answer.  `find / -type f -name '*dvorak*'` turns up a few files which `loadkeys` won't take.  As in [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179855/how-do-i-temporarily-change-the-console-keymap-to-dvorak/) I *do not* want to make a permanent change to my system using `console-config`.  I want to write simple scripts that can change the keymap on the fly.

Is there a package I can install or something?

Since I'd like to swap Caps-Lock and Escape eventually, I should probably [make my own custom keymaps](https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux), anyway, correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) Make sure `console-data` package is installed:

```
# loadkeys dvorak
Loading /usr/share/keymaps/i386/dvorak/dvorak.kmap.gz

$ dpkg --search /usr/share/keymaps/i386/dvorak/dvorak.kmap.gz
console-data: /usr/share/keymaps/i386/dvorak/dvorak.kmap.gz

$ cat /etc/debian_version 
wheezy/sid
```

2) IMHO, yes `dumpkeys > test.keymap && edit test.keymap && loadkeys test` is the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

This is a script from my personal poison cabinet which I use to permanently make CAPSLOCK an additional CTRL on debian. It should provide enough hints so you can further adapt it yourself.

It's assumed the 'us' kbd layout is used until now, new keyboard layout will be called 'sjas' here.

Oneliner:

```
apt install console-data -y; TMP=$(loadkeys us | awk {'print $2'}); TMP2=$(dirname $TMP)/sjas.kmap.gz; cp -vaf $TMP $TMP2; gzip -d $TMP2; TMP3=${TMP2%%.gz}; sed -i -e 's/us.map/sjas.map/' -e 's/.*58.*/keycode  58 = Control/' $TMP3; gzip -c $TMP3 > $TMP2; rm $TMP3; sed -i 's/"us"/"sjas"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

Not in one line, so it can be read easier:

```
apt install console-data -y
TMP=$(loadkeys us | awk {'print $2'})
TMP2=$(dirname $TMP)/sjas.kmap.gz
cp -vaf $TMP $TMP2
gzip -d $TMP2
TMP3=${TMP2%%.gz}
sed -i -e 's/us.map/sjas.map/' -e 's/.*58.*/keycode  58 = Control/' $TMP3
gzip -c $TMP3 > $TMP2
rm $TMP3
sed -i 's/"us"/"sjas"/g' /etc/default/keyboard
```

Replace 'sjas' and 'us' string occurrences with accordingly where your current layout differs and how you want to call your new one.